# How is the probability of drawing a colored ball calculated?

Tags: probability

If I have an urn with 5 white and 7 red balls, and another urn that has 7 white and 8 red balls, assuming that I randomly draw a ball from the first and place it in the second, and then I draw a white ball from the second Urn What color of sphere is most likely to have been chosen in the first urn?

I know that at the beginning, the probability of drawing a white ball at the end will be $\frac{5 \cdot 8} {12\cdot 16} = 0.20 $ if I choose a white ball in the first urn, and if I choose a red ball it will be $ \frac{7 \cdot 8}{12 \cdot 16} = 0.25 $. But I don't understand how to calculate it backwards.

Comment: `I know that at the beginning, the probability of drawing a white ball at the end will be ` this is wrong, it should be $\frac{5*8}{12*16} + \frac{7*7}{12*16}$

Comment: yes, you're right! I forgot to add them

Answer (score 1):

Let $W_1$ be the event that a white ball was chosen and transferred from the first urn.  Let $W_2$ be the event that a white ball was chosen from the second urn.

You are tasked with calculating $\Pr(W_1\mid W_2)$

Using Bayes' Theorem:

$$\Pr(W_1\mid W_2) = \dfrac{\Pr(W_2\mid W_1)Pr(W_1)}{Pr(W_2)}$$

Each of these terms on the right should be accessible to you.

> $\Pr(W_2\mid W_1) = \frac{8}{16}$, $\Pr(W_1)=\frac{5}{12}$

$~$

> $\Pr(W_2) = \Pr(W_1)\Pr(W_2\mid W_1) + \Pr(W_1^c)\Pr(W_2\mid W_1^c) = \frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{8}{16} + \frac{7}{12}\cdot \frac{7}{16}$

Comment: But for $W_1$ I would also have to do it with the red ball? Because I need to know which one is more likely to have been chosen in the first ballot box (be it red or white, not just white).

Comment: Picking a red ball in the first is just $W_1^c$.  The probability of a red ball being what was transferred from box $1$ given that a white ball was drawn in box $2$ after the transfer is $\Pr(W_1^c\mid W_2)$ which is very simply $1-\Pr(W_1\mid W_2)$